# AJAX json return causing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, vb.net, web-services

Hey all I am not sure why I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

When getting my JSON string back from an AJAX call.

My AJAX code is:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   crossDomain: true,
   dataType: 'json',
   cache: false,
   contentType: "application/json",
   url: serviceURL,
   data: JSON.stringify({ febData: ["LIST"] }),
   success: function (data) {
         var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
         //console.log(data);             
      },
   error: function (xhr, status, error) {
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
   }
});
```

The error is on the line:

```
$.parseJSON(data)
```

My returned JSON looks like this (**when using console.log(data)**):

```
[{
        "RowTitle" : "1 A Test",
        "FormName" : "F_Form1",
        "ID" : "9d91523e-5e76-47bf-860d-3bbb41933b74"
    }, {
        "RowTitle" : "1 A Test",
        "FormName" : "F_Form1",
        "ID" : "9d91523e-5e76-47bf-860d-3bbb41933b74"
    }, {
        "RowTitle" : "1 Diagnostic",
        "FormName" : "F_Form1",
        "ID" : "a97847c9-acf3-4719-8109-91bf3772c2ba"
    }, {
        "RowTitle" : "1 poll - copy",
        "FormName" : "F_Form1",
        "ID" : "435cbb7b-c3dd-43f4-84aa-61a343d6abe9"
    }, {
        "RowTitle" : "1 poll - copy",
        "FormName" : "F_Form1",
        "ID" : "435cbb7b-c3dd-43f4-84aa-61a343d6abe9"
    }, {
        "RowTitle" : "1 poll idea",
        "FormName" : "F_Form1",
        "ID" : "2fd81b31-d648-4e40-8019-a7967bb190de"
    }, {
        "RowTitle" : "1 poll idea",
        "FormName" : "F_Form1",
        "ID" : "2fd81b31-d648-4e40-8019-a7967bb190de"
    }, {
        "RowTitle" : "2015 Family Holiday Gathering",
        "FormName" : "F_Form1",
        "ID" : "9ae2d44f-8e65-465a-8802-e2ad4408afd2"
    }
]
```

I'm returning that JSON via my .net web service:

```
Dim jsonResults As String = "["

For value As Integer = 0 To result_RowTitle.Length - 1
   jsonResults += "{""RowTitle"":""" & result_RowTitle(value) & ""","
   jsonResults += """FormName"":""" & result_rowFormName(value) & ""","
   jsonResults += """ID"":""" & result_RowIDs(value) & """},"
Next

jsonResults = jsonResults.Trim().Substring(0, jsonResults.Length - 1) & "]"

Dim strResponse As String = ser.Serialize(jsonResults)

Context.Response.Clear()
Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", strResponse.Length.ToString())
Context.Response.Flush()
Context.Response.Write(strResponse)
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
```

Anyone see where it could be messing up to cause that error?

**Network screenshot req**
[image]

Created **class** as suggested:

```
Private Class febForms
    Public Property RowTitle As String
    Public Property FormName As String
    Public Property ID As String
End Class

Dim febFormData As New List(Of febForms)

For value As Integer = 0 To result_RowTitle.Length - 1
   Dim febforms As New febForms

   With febforms
      .RowTitle = result_RowTitle(value)
      .FormName = result_rowFormName(value)
      .ID = result_RowIDs(value)
   End With

   febFormData.Add(febforms)
Next

Dim strResponse As String = ser.Serialize(febFormData)

Context.Response.Clear()
Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", strResponse.Length.ToString())
Context.Response.Flush()
Context.Response.Write(strResponse)
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
```

Comment: Don't build JSON by hand.  Use a JSON serializer to serialize classes.

Comment: @SLaks Have an example to show this since I have 3 types of returned data?

Comment: Make a class with those properties.

Comment: Probably `strResponse.Length.ToString()` isn't getting you the correct size, because `content-length` must be in bytes.

Comment: Json validator http://jsonlint.com/ says that your response is correct (of course never make json by hand), so, what's your question?

The error in my opinion resides in the fact that you are trying to parse an already decoded json, jQuery does that for you... So, try `var obj = data;`

Comment: @Hitmands When i try to just do that **var obj = data;** and use something like **console.log(obj.ID)** or **console.log(obj[0].ID)** its undefined

Comment: @StealthRT try this `console.log(typeof data, data);`;
and post the result...

Comment: @Hitmands **string [{"RowTitle":"1 Di...**

Comment: if is a string and isn't decoded by jQuery, probably, you aren't setting the content-type in a right way, can you post please the response of the network panel (chrome), via screenshot for example

Comment: @Hitmands added screen shot to OP.

Comment: you should past the entire request, headers included...

Comment: @Hitmands All others were images, css, icons, etc loading.

Comment: @SLaks I posted my class code in my OP and it works now. Please put that as the answer so i can give you proper credit.

Answer (score 0):

A .Net string is multi-byte so a string length is not the same as the content length sent to the stream. This may mean that your parsing on the client is not dealing with the full JSON as the number of characters being less than the number of bytes means it is trimmed.

Something like this on the server may help:

```
Encoding encoding = HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding;
byte[] buffer = encoding.GetBytes(strResponse);
Context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
```

Your header size value should be `buffer.length`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't build JSON by hand. Use a JSON serializer to serialize classes, to ensure that your JSON is actually valid.

You also need to set `Content-Length` to the length in UTF8 bytes.  Use `Encoding.UTF8`.